# My VSCode debugger dosen't show any variable value (image attached)(c++)

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

I recently started to use VSCode and can't seem to figure out how to use the debugger.The c++ debugger dosen't show any values which are readable.

p.s i have installed the c++ intellisense extension from microsoft.

edit:[screenshot after stepping over](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oGrj.png)

[Variable not showing their values during debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OruBN.png)

my launch.json:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

  {
    "name": "g++.exe build and debug active file",
    "type": "cppdbg",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
    "args": [],
    "stopAtEntry": true,
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "environment": [],
    "externalConsole": true,
    "MIMode": "gdb",
    "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
    "setupCommands": [
      {
        "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
        "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
        "ignoreFailures": true
      }
    ],
    "preLaunchTask": "g++.exe build active file"
  }
]
```

}

my tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\MinGW\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: In the screenshot; at this point (debugging at line 9), msg is not yet initialized, thus it has no values to show... try to step over, [as in the tutorial describes I suppose you are using](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_start-a-debugging-session).

Comment: I have added an image after stepping over, the solution could not solve my issue.

Comment: I have the same problem. Check my most recent question. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Just remove the existing MinGW and instead install MinGW-W64 from here https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/ It worked for me.

Comment: yes thank you so much @StupidMan, i have to **uninstall my MinGW-w32** and had to **install MinGW-W64** as you instructed and my debugger now works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uninstalled MinGW-w32 and installed MinGW-W64 as instructed by @StupidMan